# Seg fault on fclose?

Tags: c, file-io, io, scanf

I'm trying to read a file of integers, which contains the number of integers in the file as the first integer, but when I try and close the file after reading it, I'm getting a seg fault.

I've read that if the file pointer is null and you try and close it, it will seg fault. However, I'm checking if it's null before closing it, it's not null and it's still giving me a seg fault..

I ran it through GDB and as soon as the fclose(fp) executes, it seg faults.

What's going on??

Here's my code:

```
            char *mode = "r";
            int numsToRead = 0;
            FILE *fp = fopen(inputFile, mode);

            if (fp == NULL){
                    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file!\n");
                    exit(1);
            }

            int *temp;
            int index = 0;
            // Get number of integers (first integer)
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &numsToRead);
            fprintf(stdout, "nums to read: %d\n", numsToRead);

            integers = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * numsToRead);
            for(int i = 0; i <= numsToRead; i++){
                    int currInt;
                    if(fscanf(fp, "%d", &currInt) == 1)
                            integers[i] = currInt;
                    else
                            break;
            }
            if(fp != NULL)
            fclose(fp);
```

Comment: `i <= numsToRead` should be `i < numsToRead`.

Comment: Where is your declaration of `integers`? Without a declaration it's going to default to `int`, not `int *`.

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc`!

Comment: @CoolGuy If i can't cast the result of malloc, then what do I do with the return pointer of type (void *) in order to make it usable for an integer array

Comment: Read [this](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i <= numsToRead; i++)
//               ^^
```

should be

```
for(int i = 0; i < numsToRead; i++)
//               ^
```

Comment: @JayB , Show the declaration of it and the contents of the text file.